# ¿Como repartir elementos con modulo random?

Tags: python, random

por favor solo respondan los que tienen bien claro este tema :)

Digamos que tengo 5 canastas que almacenan 20 huevos cada una **como máximo**, como hago para repartir 80 huevos en esas 5 canastas sin sobrepasar el limite de 20 huevos por canasta  pero si o si tengo que repartir los huevos en las 5 canastas.

Se que el modulo random elige un numero al azar entre dos números que yo le defina, ej: `random.randint(15, 20)`

Agarraria un numero al azar entre 15 y 20, pero es esta forma puede que los numeros que elija la funcion random no me repartan los 80 huevos que quiero repartir y me repartan menos.

Mi idea es que al final me quede un diccionario como este donde estén repartidos todos los huevos en las canastas de forma aleatoria (si alguien tiene otra propuesta que no sea mas complicada para almacenarlos, bienvenida sea!):

```
canastas = {"canasta1" : 15 , "canasta2": 18, "canasta3": 20, etc }
```

Comment: Puede que haya otra forma de hacerlo aleatoriamente sin usar random?? la verdad que no se, pero si la hay y no es complicadisima me gustaria saberlo. desde ya gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Soy de los que no tienen del todo claro el tema, pero igual, al menos puedo proponerte una solución de "fuerza bruta" que es totalmente factible. La idea es:

1. Cada canasta podría tener eventualmente de 0 a 20 huevos (21 posibilidades)
2. Podemos generar entonces al azar un numero importante pero razonable computacionalmente de 6 posibles canastas
3. Luego simplemente verificamos los supuestos de cada una de las combinaciones: la suma de las canastas debe ser 80

Esta más o menos sería la idea:

```
import random

def get_random_combination(canastas, maximo_x_canasta):
    combinacion = []
    for c in range(canastas):
        combinacion.append(random.randint(0, maximo_x_canasta+1))
    return combinacion

def is_valid_combination(combinacion, maximo_x_canasta, total_huevos):

    if sum(combinacion) != total_huevos:
        return False

    return True

for intentos in range(1000):
    combinacion = get_random_combination(6, 20)
    if is_valid_combination(combinacion, 20, 80):
        print(combinacion, sum(combinacion))

[17, 9, 18, 18, 18, 0] 80
[12, 9, 7, 18, 21, 13] 80
[20, 16, 13, 4, 12, 15] 80
[17, 20, 19, 10, 9, 5] 80
[20, 18, 20, 11, 7, 4] 80
[15, 14, 17, 18, 15, 1] 80
[10, 14, 18, 1, 17, 20] 80
[12, 9, 20, 8, 21, 10] 80
[14, 17, 6, 21, 11, 11] 80
[16, 12, 10, 20, 15, 7] 80
[20, 20, 11, 16, 7, 6] 80
[10, 18, 15, 12, 18, 7] 80
[19, 11, 16, 1, 14, 19] 80
[21, 15, 11, 19, 11, 3] 80
[17, 7, 13, 14, 19, 10] 80
[20, 20, 9, 1, 13, 17] 80
[18, 7, 18, 12, 20, 5] 80
[14, 8, 19, 11, 13, 15] 80
[17, 15, 20, 11, 12, 5] 80
[9, 9, 17, 12, 17, 16] 80
[11, 16, 8, 14, 21, 10] 80
[4, 13, 5, 20, 20, 18] 80
```

Como puedes observar, haciendo una simulación de 1000 posibles combinaciones de canastas hemos encontrado varias posibilidades que cumplen nuestros supuestos. Una posibilidad de mejora de este algoritmo, es finalizar cuando encontremos la primera combinación exitosa, que es lo que se requiere, por ejemplo:

```
import random

def try_to_get_valid_random_combination(intentos_maximos, canastas, maximo_x_canasta, total_huevos):

    for intento in range(intentos_maximos):
        combinacion = [random.randint(0, maximo_x_canasta+1) for c in range(canastas)]
        if sum(combinacion) == total_huevos:
            return combinacion

    return None

combinacion = try_to_get_valid_random_combination(1000, 6, 20, 80)
```

Y, por cierto, si buscas un diccionario puedes transformar cualquiera de las listas de combinaciones que tengas:

```
d = {}
for i, v in enumerate(combinacion,1):
    d["canasta{0}".format(i)] = v
```

Comment: de paso pregunto... si tengo un diccionario con 3 claves y 3 valores. como hago para almacenar la suma de los 3 valores del diccionario dentro de una variable que yo quiera?

Comment: @TomiBegher, dado un diccionario `d`, dónde obviamente todos los valores son numéricos, lo más sencillo es hacer `sum(d.values())`

Comment: gracias patricio!! pude aplicar este ejemplo resumido en una sola funcion como me pedian, pero me sirvio!!

Answer (score 0):

Para los proximos que vean esta pregunta y quieran una respuesta un poco mas resumida y facil de entender. lo hice asi porque me pedian todo en una funcion:

```
import random

canastas = {"canatas1": 1, "canasta2": 1, "canasta3": 1, "canasta4": 1, "canasta5": 1}
cont = 0

def carga_random(canastas,cont):
    for i in range(1, 1000):
        for x in canastas:  # que este for se repita 999 veces
            canastas[x] = random.randint(0,20)
            cont += canastas[x]
        if cont == 80:
            cont = "Del total de 80 huevos"
            return canastas, cont
        else:
            cont = 0

print(carga_random(canastas, cont))
```

OUTPUT:

```
({'canatas1': 17, 'canasta2': 14, 'canasta3': 16, 'canasta4': 17, 'canasta5': 16}, 'del total de 80 huevos')
```